# How can I order alphabetically a list in plain text in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any way to order alphabetically a list in VS Code?

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Press `Ctrl + A` to select every line, then press `Ctrl + Shift + P` to open the command palette and then search for "sort" and a few options will pop up. You will want to use either "Sort lines Ascending" or "Sort lines Descending" accordingly. I hope I helped!